# Cannot get css selector to respect margin right or left

Tags: html, css

I have the following styles defined for two divs inside a containing div.  I want to float the first inner div left and the second inner div right.  I also want to make them margin left or margin right respectively by 15px.  The problem is I want to keep my 'float left/float right' styles clean of the margin specification.

I want to be able to specify the class and add to it like so:

```
#termsPageButtonContainerCheckbox.leftAlignedControl {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

The problem is, the margin-left will only be respected when i place it in the float style:

```
.leftAlignedControl {
    float: left;
}
```

Here is a demo i set up on JSFiddle:  [Removed by OP]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not targeting the id correctly. You either need to change the HTML id to  `termsPageButtonContainerCheckbox` or change the CSS to `#termsPageForm:termsPageButtonContainerCheckbox`

http://jsfiddle.net/c5or4hjg/1/

Comment: i actually made a few mistakes here, i made these inline span elements and not div elements. It was easy for me to make this mistake as I was using JSF tags to generate the markup.  I am still unclear why using jsf tags to generate simple HTML markup is considered advantageous but thats the way I got used to doing it at the last place (they insisted)

Answer (score 1):

The button has 2 ID's, but only its only possible to give it one id and its not possible to use `:` in an id for as fas as i know. So it will work if you remove one of the 2 parts used (the one before or after `:`)